# jQuery .hide() does not excecute after AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, html

I am filling an unordered list by using an AJAX request. After filling it, I want it to be hidden instantly, so I can show it just, when it's needed. I stripped the code as much as possible, to make the point clear. The AJAX code will build me an li-element with the class=DropDownElement. As soon, as the request is completed, I want them hidden, but right now, it's not working as intended.
I guess, thats because jQuery is unable to check if new '.DropdownElements' appeared.

I am using the following code:

```
function populateDropDown (){

var currentID = $(this).attr("id");

$('.DropDownElement').remove();


$.ajax({
    url: 'xml/wooddata.xml',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(data) {

        $(data).find('wood[id="' + currentID + '"]').each(function(){

            var hasTraversal = $(this).find('images[rotation="traversal"]').children().length > 0;



            if (hasTraversal) {
                $(this).find('images[rotation="traversal"] image_description[lang="' + activeLanguage + '"]').each(function(){

                    var description = $(this).text();
                    $('#TraversalSelector').append('<li value="' + currentID + '" class="DropDownElement" id="' + currentID + '" data-rotation="traversal">' + description + '</li>');
                });
            };
        });
    }   
});

$('.DropDownElement').hide();

};
```

Comment: You have to hide your element inside the ajax success function. Remeber that you are working with an async task.

Comment: Put $('.DropDownElement').hide(); under success function (at last). Do let me know if you want me to modify your code to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ajax()` function **sends** the request. You are hiding the drop down elements after you call that function.

The elements don't exist until the **response** is received and the `success` function is called.

Move the `hide()` call inside the `success` function.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `$('.DropDownElement').hide();`  inside but last `success: function(data) {}`

```
 success: function(data) {
   ....
   $('.DropDownElement').hide();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that the javascript executes all the statements in parallel

So you should call the `.hide()` function **inside the success function** if you want it to happen after it.

**Also add a function for error: in ajax call** and call the hide function inside that too

You can also try adding a timeout

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('.DropDownElement').hide();},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

.hide works after ajax request .

condition is that's element should not be removed by $('.DropDownElement').remove(); or(like this)
after remove, any element does not hide .
for hiding,  element should be there.